# Return ONLY Most Recent Mail Date for Specific Document IDs

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-order-by

I'm trying to get an Order By clause to work for a query but it does not appear to function properly. My goal is as follows

1. Search for a specific User ID
2. Search only for the most recent Mail Date for two different Document IDs (55 and 57)
3. Order the search results by the Mail Date, so that whatever Mail Date is most recent is displayed at the top of the list
4. Only return the first row, which should be the most recent mailed letter for either of the Document IDs listed

The issue I am running in to is that the `ORDER BY` clause does not appear to work. The user I am testing it with has a document with the `doc_def_id` of "55" and a `mailed_date` of 06/22/2018, and a document with the `doc_def_id` of "57" and a `mailed_date` of 07/08/2018. To my knowledge it should give me the `doc_def_id` of "57" because it has a more recent mail date, but it seems to ignore the `ORDER BY` clause and gives me the first result (as if there was no `ORDER BY` clause) no matter what.

Code:

```
SELECT
    ual.user_id,
    ual.account_id,
    dr.mailed_date, 
    dr.doc_def_id 
FROM doc_request dr
JOIN user_account_link ual 
    ON dr.account_id = ual.account_id
WHERE 
    ual.user_id = '123456'
    AND dr.mailed_date = (
        SELECT Max(dr.mailed_date)
         FROM doc_request
          WHERE ual.user_id = '123456'
          AND dr.doc_def_id IN ('55','57')
    )
AND ROWNUM <= 1
ORDER BY dr.mailed_date DESC;
```

Comment: The 55 or 57 condition is needed in both main query and subquery.

Comment: I added the condition to the main query as well, but it still gives me the same result. To clarify (and I just realized I forgot to finish the title so I will edit that if I can), I get the most recent mail date for each document type if I remove the ROWNUM condition, however I can't get the ORDER BY to give me the most recent mail date at the top.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ROWNUM should used in outer query to get exact max date.

```
select * from
(SELECT ual.user_id, ual.account_id, dr.mailed_date, dr.doc_def_id 
FROM doc_request dr

join user_account_link ual ON dr.account_id = ual.account_id

WHERE ual.user_id = '123456'

AND dr.mailed_date = (SELECT Max(dr.mailed_date)
  FROM doc_request
  WHERE ual.user_id = '123456'
  AND dr.doc_def_id IN ('55','57'))

ORDER BY dr.mailed_date DESC)
WHERE ROWNUM=1;
```

Comment: This does seem to have solved it. Thanks a ton for the help, another person and I have been trying to figure this out for days. It never occurred to us to put everything a layer deeper like this.

Answer (score 1):

More recent Oracle versions support the ANSI SQL `FETCH FIRST` clause:

```
SELECT ual.user_id, ual.account_id, dr.mailed_date, dr.doc_def_id 
FROM doc_request dr
join user_account_link ual ON dr.account_id = ual.account_id
WHERE ual.user_id = '123456'
  AND dr.doc_def_id IN ('55','57')
ORDER BY dr.mailed_date DESC
FETCH FIRST 1 ROW ONLY
```

Comment: Even if you use a subquery with `rownum`, this is better than the alternative answer.